# How to fix weak/bad sectors (Pending sector count:2812-S.M.A.R.T attribute 1TB HP p3100 ext hd) due to read/write CRC error?

Tags: bad-sectors, crc

I have tried a plethora of software HD sentinel,HDD regenerator,HD tune pro,Victoria,HDD scan,Spinrite,Low level format tool,chkdsk,windows full format and virtually every other software possible but nothing seem to work.Everything takes a lot of time and gets stuck at particular point.Before i moved the data and quick formatted it and used above mentioned software.**(S.M.A.R.T: Pending SEC-2812 ;Spin up time:5000 to 6000;Ultra ATA error:6)**. 
RAN:

1. HDD regenerator in mode 3 it reported device not ready after sometime.
2. HD sentinel reinitialise disk surface which didn't work(often got stuck and wouldn't respond).First 
   bad bloks were becz of error 23:CRC and after months of meddling with a lot of HDD diagnostic tools the 
   error became error 21:device not ready.
3. Spinrite gave warning not to perform any operations on that disk(Holy Shit!!).
4. chkdsk-stuck at 10%.
5. full format & low level format using hdd guru-device not ready
6. Even stranger thing badblocks reported read/write error and then HDD's LED went off until i 
   disconnected and reconnected hdd.

Is there any means to magically hide/reallocate those bad sectors to use remnant sectors?

OR at-least is there a way to store file in that hd skipping bad sectors?

Destructive/Non-destructive anything works fine.I want to experiment on this hdd becz i don'think there is a way to revive it.So i'm up for any crazy stuff.

If Possible anything fast and  less time consuming or not involving pc to be run for a week straight up

PS:Did i make it worse???

Comment: Easy, drive is dying beyond repair. Make backups and replace with new drive. HDD's and SSD's don't have infinite life span.

Comment: Yes, and back up any data on it before it is too late.

Comment: Bad sectors cannot be fixed. They are bad. Backups should already be in place, you shouldn't be scrabbling around now trying to do them.

Comment: **Moderator Warning** - please do not use obscenities in your posts. I've removed it for you. Note that other users may have flagged your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](https://superuser.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"

Comment: Sometimes the magnetic coating on a platter comes off. It then scratches more coating off, which cascades into a destroyed platter surface and damaged read/write heads. Maybe that happened to the HDD in question. Assuming you have all the data off the drive, you could disassemble it and get two magnets out of it. N.B. Once you have opened the drive, it is definitely dead.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any means to magically hide/reallocate those bad sectors to
>   use remnant sectors?

The drive is bad. Hard drives have a limited number of spare sectors to replace bad sectors and this is limited to “normal operation.” Once the drive is generating thousands or even dozens of bad sectors it is time to replace it.

No tool can make a bad hard drive in to a good hard drive.

> PS:Did i make it worse???

Yes. Every moment the drive is powered on you are making it worse.

Comment: How about a magnet? Can i use it to erase unreadable/unwritable sectors.Already backed up and HDD is empty.

Answer (score 0):

First of all just like Appleoddity said there is no way of fixing BAD sectors.

**YOUR DRIVE IS BAD DO NOT STORE ANY VALUABLE DATA ON IT!!!!**

Since you say you want to experiment with the drive here is the info.

They can be hidden, but they are still there.

If the error is so bad chkdsk fails more drastic action is necessary.

Does chkdsk give a sector number?

Clusters are typically 4k so if you get a cluster number you need to multiple it by the cluster size.

Each sector is 512 bytes on a 1tb hdd so if sector 12,100 was bad 12,100/2= position of 6050kb.  So you would have to manually from the command line using diskpart or similar create a partition starting position of 8mb.  The bad sector is at approx 6mb, but we want a buffer zone between them.  In the interest of saving time you may just want to jump ahead 100mb at a time.

This is could be a trail and error process as we don't know exactly how many bad sectors there are, but eventually you will end up with some amount of usable space.  You may also have to reduce the ending position of the drive and lose additional capacity.

You may or may not be force to use quick format because of the bad sectors.  After you successfully format the drive a chkdsk /r will be required to mark the remaining bad sectors bad.

To make the changes even more permanent you can use software to adjust the HBA of the hard drive to tell it to hide a certain number of sectors at the beginning or end of the drive.  Yes, you will lose a corresponding amount of capacity on your 1tb hdd.

Comment: Result of chkdsk /r:244160424 free clusters processed.Free space verification is complete.                                                                                                          
Read failure with status 0xc00000a3 at offset 0x2000 for 0x1000 bytes.
The MFT mirror starting at cluster 0x2 for 0x8 sectors
cannot be read.
Correcting errors in the Master File Table (MFT) mirror.
Insufficient disk space to repair master file table (MFT) mirror.

Comment: Your suggestion might be helpful if bad sectors were contiguous as opposed to being scattered.Which is not in my case.Even then i need to know where are the bad sectors.The biggest problem is that bad sectors are unreadable/unwritable if only there is a way to zero in all those sectors it would be fine.I know that the inception of the problem was CRC error.Is it a logical bad sector.BTW i did try re partitioning just 1GB of space and ran chkdsk which finished without error saying 4KB of bad sector.If atleast this would happen will operation on whole hard drive i would be glad.

Comment: i'm using cygwin.can e2fsck command do the magic??

Comment: @Kishore Do which magic? Check for bad sectors?  badblocks -v /dev/sda10 > badsectors.txt Followed by: e2fsck -l badsectors.txt /dev/sda10   Also then you should have a list of bad sectors, and you can create a partition in the largest amount of undamaged space.

Comment: First of all badblocks commands take too long to initiate after executing the command.And i read from another source that e2fsck command is only efficient for older hard drives which is not capable of managing bad sectors unlike the modern hard drive.So my question is if i use e2fsck command does it mark sectors and instruct windows not to use those sector for using data which is more reasonable and useful than partitioning only undamaged space which isn't much in my case

Comment: Yes, e2fsck -l badsectors.txt /dev/sda10  Hides the bad sectors found in the badsectors.txt file so they aren't used.  You keep saying windows and e2fsck, these are usually mutual exclusive.  Windows use NTFS and linux has ext(2,3,4) and chkdsk /R is used for NTFS and e2fsck is used for ext(2,3,4).  Please clarify what is happening?  Did you load a special driver so windows understands ext(2,3,4) because it doesn't support it natively.

Comment: i am using cygwin on windows 7.So is there a command for ntfs file system with same functionality as e2fsck